# I cannot get ng-class working when the class I am adding has a hyphen in it .

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a class to my  element in Angular.  Here's my code:

```
   <button class="medium"
      data-ng-disabled="!gridForm.$pristine || fetching.length != 0"
      data-ng-click="getQuestions()">
      Retrieve<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-fw mlr75" data-ng-class="{fa-spin: fetching.length > 0}">     </span>
   </button>
```

However it's giving me a strange error:

```
Syntax Error
error in component $parse
Syntax Error: Token '-' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be wrong? Note that it works when I use the class faspin without the hyphen !!

Comment: try exclosing between '', like `'my-class'`. In your case, you could try: `data-ng-class="{'fa-spin': fetching.length > 0}"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surround class name with singe quotation.

```
data-ng-class="{'fa-spin': fetching.length > 0}"
```

Otherwise angular search your scope for `fa-spin` which is not a valid name for variables.